# Run Query Inside a Loop

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a function in my model that executes a query. i need to run this query a specified number of times. Here is the code i am using.

```
public function populate_relations(){
    $nombre_parents_texte = $this->input->post('nombre_parents');
    $nombre_parents = (int)$nombre_parents_texte;

    for($i=0; $i=3; $i++){

        $data = array(
            'user_id'   =>$this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'annees_service'=>$nombre_parents,
            'fonction' => $i
        );

        $insert_data_1 = $this->db->insert('relations', $data);
    }
    return $insert_data_1;
}
```

When running the function, it gets executed more than 500 times, and the value of 'fonction' is always the last value of 'i', which is 3.

Any idea why this is happening ?

Thanks,

Samer

Comment: Fix your loop condition `$i < 3`

Comment: Thanks. it worked. didn't notice this at all. i have been working on it since morning.

Comment: It is more cost-effective to configure an array with data through that loop and after the loop to use `insert_batch()` [method](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data).

Comment: use insert_batch() codeignitor function and it's best practice and also save your execution time .
Open this -
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: I will try it tonight. Thanks